# Get the last div element using cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Hello I am implementing a **scraper** which scrape the latest message received in a telegram public channel. This is how the html is [image]

I can fetch all the divs under section class `tgme_channel_history`. It has five divs under it which means five different messages. I want to get only the last div. How can I do that.
You can check the live HTML here https://telegram.me/s/newlink01/

```
const $ = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://telegram.me/s/newlink01/';

 rp(url)
        .then(function (html) {
            //success!
            const wikiUrls = [];

            $('.tgme_channel_history', html).each(function () {

                wikiUrls.push($(this).text()


            });
            console.log(wikiUrls[0]);

  })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //handle error
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a selector to [`jQuery.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to select all child `div` elements, and then call [`jQuery.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to fetch the final one in the set.

```js
$(".tgme_channel_history").children("div").last();
```

Comment: Thank you very much